# Update icloud calendar via php curl

Tags: php, curl, calendar, icloud, icalendar

I want to realize a script for managing events to a shared icloud calendar.
I've stored on my db several events and, on request, i need to create an event to be seen on remote phones/ipad and so on.

Thanks to Andy and his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416501/icloud-caldav-via-php) I had no problem for write an event to icloud, but when I try to update or delete an event, icloud doesn't seem to record any change.
Below you can find part of the function I use to create the event

```
$body = <<<__EOD
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-// blablabla
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
METHOD:UPDATE
UID:$id
DTSTAMP:$tstamp
ORGANIZER;CN=$organizer:MAILTO:$email
DTSTART:$tstart
DTEND:$tend
SUMMARY:$name
LOCATION:$location
DESCRIPTION:$description
SEQUENCE:2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
__EOD;



$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8',
    'If-None-Match: *',
    'Expect: ',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($body),
);



// CONNESSIONE E SCRITTURA


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) echo 'Curl error: '.curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

If I exclude the connection to the icloud server and print $body the .ics generated update without any problem my local calendar (and then replicate the changes to icloud).
Otherwise if I try to connect to icloud it won't save the changes.
I've tried to change the server request but still can't get out of it

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'If-None-Match: *', from the headers. This will allow you to update to the iCal with the 'PUT' command.

Hope this helps.